# I cant' access my data from database'data in array

Tags: react-native

I try to get data from database by use 'getDoc' and .then(). After I get data I push it to the array. But when i acces data in then() i can access. But after i access in sam function, after get out from then(). i can't access. Sorry to bad naming.

```
    const totalDBPromise2 = getDocs("Road");
    let loaded2 = false;
    let totalDB2 = [];

    let totalNameDB2 = []
    totalDBPromise2.then((querySnapshot) => {
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        if (!totalDB2.includes(doc.data())) {
          totalDB2[doc.data().name] = doc.data()
        }
        loaded2 = true;
      });
      console.log(totalDB2['road1']) //I can access. I can get right result
    });
    console.log(totalDB2['road1']) // I can access. The result was undefined
```

I try to make it work. But i fail to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your second console runs before you'r first and before your promise resolved.
** totalDBPromise2** is a promise and it will take time to get values.

so use async/await or use useState which will reflect when changes made to state